# hide the div with the form after the form is submitted and show a hidden div

Tags: javascript, forms, hide, show, onsubmit

so I have this

```
    <div id="first" class="1" style="display:">
        <form>
            <input type=submit>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="second" class="2" style="display:none">
        test
    </div>
```

I want to switch the display option after the form is submitted (the button is pushed). I want the script to become like this after clicking on the submit button

```
    <div id="first" class="1" style="display:none">
        <form>
            <input type=submit>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="second" class="2" style="display:">
        test
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add an `onsubmit` handler. Without using a third-party library such as jQuery, here's a basic way to do it with inline JavaScript:

```
<form onsubmit="document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('second').style.display = '';">
```

The `onsubmit` is triggered whenever the form is submitted, be it by clicking the `Submit` button, programmatically, or if a user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a textfield, for example.

I would, however, recommend you use jQuery and a more unobtrusive approach than this inline approach though. If you want to see how to do that with jQuery, here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw6SL/1/) that shows one way of accomplishing this. Basically, you would add an `id` such as `myform` on the `form` element and then add this to your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
        $("#first").hide();
        $("#second").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First give id to submit button.

```
<div id="first" class="1" style="display:">
    <form>
        <input type=submit **id="submit-btn"**>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="second" class="2" style="display:none">
    test
</div>
```

Then write Click Event of submit Button

```
jQuery("#submit-btn").click(function(e)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#first').hide();
    jQuery('#show').show();
}
```